# "Error in as.Date.numeric(e) : 'origin' must be supplied" when adding rows

Tags: r, date

I have a dataframe, `df`, like so:

```
df
        date periodNumber  value
1 2020-02-02            0   814
2 2020-02-09            0  1592
3 2020-02-09            1  1808
4 2020-02-16            0  2746
5 2020-02-16            1  2646
6 2020-02-16            2  2993

str(df)
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ date        : Date, format: "2020-02-02" "2020-02-09" "2020-02-09" "2020-02-16" ...
 $ periodNumber: int  0 0 1 0 1 2
 $ value       : num  814 1592 1808 2746 2646 2993
```

As can ben seen, `df$date` is in the `Date` format. I have a for loop to add rows to this dataframe, like so:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  df[nrow(df)+1,] <- c(df$date[i]+1, df$periodNumber[i], df$periodNumber[i])
}
```

However, this gives the error `Error in as.Date.numeric(e) : 'origin' must be supplied`. Why is this? The loop works if I remove the `Date` column. I've also tried versions of adding `as.Date()` to the for loop, but that gives the same error. For example, the code below gives the same error:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  df[nrow(df)+1,] <- c(as.Date(df$date[i], origin='1970-01-01')+1, df$periodNumber[i], df$periodNumber[i])
}
```

Comment: Could you provide `dput(head(df,3))` so that others can test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `c` in the `for` loop wants to coerce the three values into a single format.

In `?c` we can read:

> The output type is determined from the highest type of the components in the hierarchy NULL < raw < logical < integer < double < complex < character < list < expression. [...] factors are treated only via their internal integer codes.

I'm actually not sure where `"Date"` where date can be categorized here. One might expect that it would be coerced to *numeric*, but it's *date*. And because there is no `origin=` supplied (where should it actually be defined??) it throws an error.

This is actually interesting, since

```
c(1, as.Date("2020-01-01"))
# [1]     1 18262
```

but

```
c(as.Date("2020-01-01"), 1)
# Error in as.Date.numeric(e) : 'origin' must be supplied
```

This is at least an inconsistency, maybe a bug, I could not find any documentation.

**Anyway**, use `data.frame` to allow for multiple classes.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  df[nrow(df)+1,] <- data.frame(df$date[i]+1, df$periodNumber[i], df$periodNumber[i])
}
#          date periodNumber value
# 1  2020-02-02            0   814
# 2  2020-02-09            0  1592
# 3  2020-02-09            1  1808
# 4  2020-02-16            0  2746
# 5  2020-02-16            1  2646
# 6  2020-02-16            2  2993
# 7  2020-02-03            0     0
# 8  2020-02-10            0     0
# 9  2020-02-10            1     1
# 10 2020-02-17            0     0
# 11 2020-02-17            1     1
# 12 2020-02-17            2     2
```

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(date = structure(c(18294, 18301, 18301, 18308, 
18308, 18308), class = "Date"), periodNumber = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 2L), value = c(814L, 1592L, 1808L, 2746L, 2646L, 2993L
)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "data.frame")
```